# c# do while functional equivalent?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, do-while

I'm writing a console app that makes webservice calls and receives XML back, and in that XML will be entries that are either "folders" or "documents". I have written the following do while loop in C# to cycle through calling the webservice, but I was wondering if there was a more functional way to do it:

```
 ...
        var documentUrls = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // get the root folder's children
        var rootFeed = $"{baseUrl}/biprws/infostore/{23}/children"
            .Do(str => Console.WriteLine($"{str}:"))
            .GetResponse(headerToken)
            .GetXmlString()
            .DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>();

        var folderUrls = rootFeed.Entries
            .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "folder"))
            .Select(entry => $"{entry.Link.Href}/children")
            .ToList();

        // go through each folder and pull out the documents - if a nested folder is found then check that too
        do
        {
            var feeds = folderUrls
                .Select(url => url.GetResponse(headerToken).GetXmlString().DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>())
                .SelectMany(x => x.Entries);

            var folders = feeds
                .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "Folder"))
                .Select(x => $"{x.Link.Href}/children")
                .ToList();

            var documents = feeds
                .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "webi"))
                .ToDictionary(
                    keySelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "id").First().Text,
                    elementSelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "name").First().Text);

            // if there are no more folders or documents to check, break out of this while loop
            if (!documents.Any() && !folders.Any())
                break;

            Console.WriteLine($"Got {folders.Count} folders and {documents.Count} documents");

            folderUrls.RemoveAll(x => true); // remove all the folder urls as they have already been checked!!!!
            folderUrls.AddRange(folders);
            documents.ForEachDo(x => documentUrls.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
        } while (true);

        Console.WriteLine($"There are {documentUrls.Count()} {nameof(documentUrls)}");
...
```

Comment: what is the end condition? your do..while loop is endless at the moment. In haskell one would implement it as recursive call or not? But with an endless recursive call you will likely receive a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Since it's just an infinite loop you might as well do a regular `while` loop.

Comment: A more 'functional' approach would be to use recursion but what you have is fine and in many ways preferable when it comes to adding error handling. A `Queue<T>` for the folders would be neater than a List that you keep wiping.

Comment: @juharr the break means it's not infinite.

Comment: @TryToSolveItSimple There's a `break` in there when there are no more documents or folders found.

Comment: @TryToSolveItSimple the end condition was both the folders and documents being empty which would break out of the loop

Comment: @Ian I only meant the loop structure itself.

Comment: @IanMercer Or a `Stack`.  That's what I usually use if I need to convert a deeply recursive algorithm to not trip up on a stack overflow.

Comment: In the line `var folderUrls = rootFeed.Entries.Where(entry => entry...)`, what is the type of `entry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this more functional is not so much about whether you use `for`, `while` or recursion. It's mainly about avoiding side effects.

E.g. how you are using `folderUrls` to keep track of already checked and nested folders is not very functional. Instead, design a *function* that takes a list of folders and returns documents. I.e. define clear inputs and outputs. From your code sample it was kinda hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Here is how this function could looke like:

```
// I don't know what the type of "entry" is. Replace "TEntry" with the correct type.
public IEnumerable<TEntry> LoadDocuments(IEnumerable<TEntry> feedEntries)
{
    var folderUrls = feedEntries
        .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "folder"))
        .Select(entry => $"{entry.Link.Href}/children");

    if (!folderUrls.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<TEntry>();

    var feeds = folderUrls
        .Select(url => url.GetResponse(headerToken)
                          .GetXmlString()
                          .DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>())
        .SelectMany(x => x.Entries)
        .ToList();

    // Recursive call to load nested documents.    
    var nestedDocuments = LoadDocuments(feeds);

    var documents = feeds
        // What's the type of "entry" here? Use that type for the return type of this 
        // function.
        .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "webi"));

    return documents.Concat(nestedDocuments);
}
```

Call it and turn the output of this function into a dictionary as you did before:

```
var rootFeed = $"{baseUrl}/biprws/infostore/{23}/children"
    .Do(str => Console.WriteLine($"{str}:"))
    .GetResponse(headerToken)
    .GetXmlString()
    .DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>();

var documentUrls = LoadDocuments(rootFeed.Entries)
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr
              .Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "id")
              .First().Text,
        x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr
              .Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "name")
              .First().Text);
```

Comment: It was the folderUrls variable in my code that I didn't like (a side effect as you mention), but I couldn't see a way to do the code any other way than as a do...while loop. I've just tried what you have put and that works!

Answer (score 1):

A pattern without an infinite loop would normally pre-load for the exit condition before the loop,

```
    var folders = feeds
            .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "Folder"))
            .Select(x => $"{x.Link.Href}/children")
            .ToList();

    var documents = feeds
            .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "webi"))
            .ToDictionary(
                keySelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "id").First().Text,
                elementSelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "name").First().Text);
```

and then use the while loop condition as an exit test:

```
while(documents.Any() || folders.Any()){

        var feeds = folderUrls
            .Select(url => url.GetResponse(headerToken).GetXmlString().DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>())
            .SelectMany(x => x.Entries);

        Console.WriteLine($"Got {folders.Count} folders and {documents.Count} documents");

        folderUrls.RemoveAll(x => true); // remove all the folder urls as they have already been checked!!!!
        folderUrls.AddRange(folders);
        documents.ForEachDo(x => documentUrls.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
```

and finally load the variables for the exit condition before looping again:

```
        folders = feeds
            .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "Folder"))
            .Select(x => $"{x.Link.Href}/children")
            .ToList();

        documents = feeds
            .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "webi"))
            .ToDictionary(
                keySelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "id").First().Text,
                elementSelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "name").First().Text);

}

...
```

This approach repeats code, so **create methods for each of the queries so the repeated code is just a few calls to the appropriate methods**.  This will result in more readable code since a descriptive method name is a lot easier to follow in the code than a LINQ query (not to mention that it won't have an infinite loop in it).  This pattern can require a bit more effort to handle variable scope, but in this case, that shouldn't be an issue (`feed` should be the only parameter to the methods in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Care about typization by yourself

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var documentUrls = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Feed rootFeed = $"{baseUrl}/biprws/infostore/{23}/children"
        .Do(str => Console.WriteLine($"{str}:"))
        .GetResponse(headerToken)
        .GetXmlString()
        .DeserializeFromXml<Library.Children.Feed>();

    IEnumerable<object> folderUrls = rootFeed.Entries
        .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "folder"))
        .Select(entry => $"{entry.Link.Href}/children")
        .ToList();

    object feeds;
    object folders;
    object documents;

    Init(folderUrls, out feeds, out folders, out documents);

    while (documents.Any() || folders.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got {folders.Count} folders and {documents.Count} documents");

        folderUrls.RemoveAll(x => true);
        folderUrls.AddRange(folders);
        documents.ForEachDo(x => documentUrls.Add(x.Key, x.Value));

        Init(folderUrls, out feeds, out folders, out documents);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {documentUrls.Count()} {nameof(documentUrls)}");

}

private static void Init(object foldersUrl, out object feeds, out object folders, out object documents)
{
    feeds = InitFeeds(foldersUrl);
    folders = InitFolders(feeds);
    documents = InitDocs(feeds);
}

private static object InitDocs(object feeds)
{
    var documents = feeds
        .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "webi"))
        .ToDictionary(
            keySelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "id").First().Text,
            elementSelector: x => x.Content.Attrs.Attr.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower() == "name").First().Text);
    return documents;
}

private static object InitFolders(object feeds)
{
    var folders = feeds
        .Where(entry => entry.Content.ContentContainsFolderUrl(type: "Folder"))
        .Select(x => $"{x.Link.Href}/children")
        .ToList();
    return folders;
}

private static object InitFeeds(object folderUrls)
{
    var feeds = folderUrls
        .Select(url => url.GetResponse(headerToken).GetXmlString().DeserializeFromXml<Feed>())
        .SelectMany(x => x.Entries);
    return feeds;
}
```